# ¿Por qué no funciona esta funcion en jquery? Array, autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, autocompletar

Intento hacer un autocompletar, al que le voy a pasar un array que es sacado de una base de datos. Al empezar a escribir en mi input vaya buscando las coincidencias con el `Nombre` y me devuelva los demás valores que voy a poner inputs de tipo `hidden` para posteriormente enviarlos por un formulario.

Este es el código que tengo:

```js
// var datos = JSON.parse('<?= addslashes(json_encode($data)) ?>');

var datos = [
{'id':'1','codigo':'0001','nombre':'Botella verde', 'importe':'10'},

{'id':'2','codigo':'0002','nombre':'Botella roja','importe':'10'}];
$(function(){
    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        lookup: datos,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            console.log(suggestion);
             alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.id + ', ' + suggestion.codigo + ', ' + suggestion.nombre+', '+suggestion.importe);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.devbridge-autocomplete/1.2.7/jquery.devbridge-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<?php
$query = $db->query("SELECT id, codigo, nombre, importe FROM productos" );
$data = [];
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
$data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>-->

<input type="text" name="country" id="autocomplete"/>
```

Todo esto lo he copiado siguiendo este ejemplo que he encontrado por internet:

https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/n6oLLfmc/

En su caso funciona, en el mío no. Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal? Qué tengo que hacer para que funcione en mi caso? Este problema me tiene hasta las narices =(

EDICION:

Este es el mismo fiddle editado solo cambiando los valores que yo uso:

https://jsfiddle.net/n6oLLfmc/5/

no funciona

Comment: Acabo de añadir el mimso enlace que en ese fiddle y he puesto el jquery pero aun así no funciona. Una cosa que me he fijado es que si pongo comillas en los indices del array que son numericos no funciona, pero si las quito si que funciona, es decir en el ejemplo hay un indice tal que así: `'data':1` (de esta forma funciona) si yo pongo `'data':'1'` no funciona... por qué es esto y como puedo solucionarlo.

Comment: Acabo de editarlo y he añadido un jsfiddle que es lo mismo que el de anes pero modificado con mis variables...

Comment: Puedes explicar que intentas conseguir ? "En su caso funciona, en el mío no"

Comment: El autocompletar, en el original si escribes una letra te busca coincidencias y te las sugiere, en mi caso cuando escribo, no funcion, no busca coincidencias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según [la documentación](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) debes entregar las propiedades `data` y `value` y en su lugar estás usando `id` y `nombre`:

> `lookup`: Callback function or lookup array for the suggestions. It may
>   be array of strings or suggestion object literals. suggestion: An
>   object literal with the following format: `{ value: 'string', data: any }`.

La versión correcta sería:

```js
var datos = [
{'data':'1','codigo':'0001','value':'Botella verde', 'importe':'10'},
{'data':'2','codigo':'0002','value':'Botella roja','importe':'10'}];
$(function(){
    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        lookup: datos,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            console.log(suggestion);
             alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data + ', ' + suggestion.codigo);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.devbridge-autocomplete/1.2.7/jquery.devbridge-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="country" id="autocomplete"/>
```

Comment: Y como puedo "adaptar" este a lo que yo necesito? o usar el oficial de jquery para lo mismo que hace el del fiddle que he pulicado?

Comment: Cambiando la forma en la que generas los datos, por lo que puedo observar es un PHP. En él debes cambiarle el nombre a los campos (por ejemplo con un alias de SQL).

Comment: He enviado un mensaje por el chat para no hacer esto más extenso.